# Renew an SSL certiticate on IIS without impacting people that using this certificate

Tags: iis, ssl, https, certificate, renewal

I have a question about renewal SSL certificate on IIS and windows server 2008.

I have a certificate that will expire 2014-10-01
We have the new certificate to install that will expire 2016-01-01.
It's the same certificate. We have only one that will expire 2 years later.

We have some people that using our certificate.

My question is about how I have to install it without impacting the other that using this certificate.

(1)Can I install the new ssl certificate now and the other people have until 2014-01-01 to install the new one.

OR

(2)I have to synchronise the installation of the certificate with all the people that using the certificate.

I want to know if I can do the (1) option and why it's possible or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I contact a professional that deliver ssl certificate and it asked at my question.
We can install the new certificate and it's seemless for other user using this certificate.
The other users have until the expiration date of the old certificate to install the new one.

Thanks